# Web Logic 12c Cluster Server generates HTTP status code 504: Gateway Time-Out. The time out Session is set to 3600 Seconds

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, cluster-computing, weblogic12c

I am working on a production Issue for a insurance sector project.

Technology : Jax-WS web services in java, Java Orchestration of Core functionality Services in Proxy Services, Deployed in Clustered Weblogic 12c Console - Clustering done for different physical location having logically bind by only one physical location.

Description : A web services (Proxy) consume other web services (Core Functionality service), more than one, does orchestration and at last sends a mail with the complete set of response in xls file format.
This is developed to handle around 50,000 records from database (retrieved by another core functionality service) and then generate the xls file.

Issue : The proxy service deployed in any of the cluster, gives
EJB Exception: : com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 504: Gateway Time-Out

On hit and trial testing, I observed the Proxy Service is having timeout in 150 to 180 seconds. The core service, fetching data from database takes around 15 min -18 mins to retrieve data and returns the response to the calling proxy service.

Even after the timeout exception is returned by the proxy service to the calling java client, the core services continues to execute till the response is generated.

The Server configuration is handle by the Client Itself.

The time out Session is set to  3600 Seconds.

Please suggest a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Configured individual Time Out Session of each of the deployed services in web logic